# Difference Between Android.bp and Android.mk

Tags: android, build-system

In Android O framework code, we see both Android.bp and Android.mk files. What is the need for both files? As per documentation .bp files are used for soong build system. When we do a build which file will be executed? .mk or .bp?

Answer (score 19):

[Soong](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/) is a build system for Android, intended as a replacement for the old [make-based build system](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/). Soong reads `Android.bp` files, which define modules in a Bazel-like syntax. 
Soong itself is written in Go on top of the [Blueprint](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/blueprint/) framework, which in turn uses [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) as a back-end. Ninja is designed for high efficiency, especially for incremental builds.

Because Android is a large project, the move to Soong/`Android.bp` will take some time. During the transitionary period, both formats are supported, with Soong for `Android.bp`, and [Kati](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/kati/) for `Android.mk`. A standard build will run both. Modules in `Android.mk` files can depend on modules in `Android.bp` files,  but not the other way.

An important difference of `Android.bp` is the absence of explicit if-statements to increase performance. Whereas `Android.mk` files can contain `ifeq` checks over arbitrary environment variables, the `Android.bp` format only allows to differentiate pre-defined cases such as processor architecture or debug/release builds ([reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/#how-do-i-write-conditionals)). Custom case distinctions have to be defined separately in Go ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602427/what-is-art-go-and-why-is-it-considered-a-way-to-write-conditionals-in-bp-files/56626010#56626010)).

Because of the design differences, automatic conversion of `Android.mk` to `Android.bp` is not feasible,
though there is a tool called [androidmk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/soong/#convert-android_mk-files) that can translate simple
`Android.mk` files (e.g. no if-statements) to `Android.bp`.

Comment: Any good resources to help one easily determine the alternative dependencies that are equivalently supported by Android.bp?  For example, I am trying to add the libVLC lib to my project when migrating to bp from mk. I cant get the exact architecture so I feel like for bp there might have been an alternative library (or typecase).